# SQL Server 2012 - MAX() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I am pulling data from 3 separate employee related tables, all joined on SSN.  Because some employees have transferred within the company multiple times they have multiple hire/separation dates in the system, so when I pull from that table with the hire dates, it duplicates the row by the number of hire/separation dates in the system.  Here's the data sample as it's pulled:

```
SSN         Name        Pay_Date    Hire_Date
123456789   John Doe    5/1/2012    1/1/2001
123456789   John Doe    5/1/2012    2/5/2005
123456789   John Doe    5/1/2012    3/1/2012
123456789   John Doe    5/15/2012   1/1/2001
123456789   John Doe    5/15/2012   2/5/2005
123456789   John Doe    5/15/2012   3/1/2012
123456789   John Doe    5/29/2012   1/1/2001
123456789   John Doe    5/29/2012   2/5/2005
123456789   John Doe    5/29/2012   3/1/2012
```

The query:

```
SELECT

SSN, Name, Pay_Date, Hire_Date

FROM Personnel as PER

LEFT JOIN Payroll as PAY on PER.SSN = PAY.SSN

LEFT JOIN HumanResources as HR on PER.SSN = HR.SSN

ORDER BY Pay_Date(DESC)
```

To eliminate the rows with hire dates 1/1/2001 and 2/5/2005, I tried using the MAX function as follows with no luck.  I tried using a variety of the examples posted on previous topics related to MAX but nothing is working.

```
SELECT

SSN, Name, Pay_Date, MAX(Hire_Date)

FROM Personnel as PER

LEFT JOIN Payroll as PAY on PER.SSN = PAY.SSN

LEFT JOIN HumanResources as HR on PER.SSN = HR.SSN

GROUP BY SSN

ORDER BY Pay_Date(DESC)
```

Again, I just need the row with the latest hire date. So the outcome should look like

```
SSN         Name        Pay_Date    Hire_Date
123456789   John Doe    5/1/2012    3/1/2012
123456789   John Doe    5/15/2012   3/1/2012
123456789   John Doe    5/29/2012   3/1/2012
```

Comment: Can you show the base tables for your example ?

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT SSN, 
                   Name, 
                   Pay_Date, 
                   Hire_Date,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SSN, Name, Pay_Date ORDER BY Hire_Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM     Personnel as PER
    LEFT JOIN Payroll as PAY on  PER.SSN = PAY.SSN
    LEFT JOIN HumanResources as HR on PER.SSN = HR.SSN
)
SELECT * 
FROM    MyCTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a4a5/2) **Powered by Lamak**

Comment: +1. You have a typo in your code (you wrote `ORDE BY`, it's missing the `R`). And [here is a sqlffidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a4a5/2) with a demo of your code

Comment: I edited my answer. I am writing from my phone so couldn't really use fiddle. May i use your sample with your permission?

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos yes you can use my sample.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos it is still repeating. I adjusted my join type, which in this case shouldn't matter, however it is continuing to repeat.  Does the number of fields I have matter?  Because in reality there are 39 per row.

Comment: Try to create some sample data with all the fields in sql fiddle and the we ll see how we can help.

Comment: I think this is what OP is looking for if you take Pay_Date from the PARTITION BY clause.  Ultimately would be the same as my post below but using the CTE as done here, I think, is more elegant.

Comment: @Greenspark Based on the given sample (input data and expected results) and as you can see in Lamak's fiddle i included in my solution, the solution should work. If it doesn't then the question should be modified.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos I stand corrected.  There was some room for confusion since OP specifically asks for 'the row' and his initial attempts only grouped on SSN -- but the given expected results match your query.  Apologies for putting words in your mouth.

Comment: @Greenspark I never complaint for a well mannered comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is it the latest Pay date and hire date? if so this should work.

```
SELECT

SSN, Name, MAX(Pay_Date), MAX(Hire_Date)

FROM Personnel as PER

LEFT JOIN Payroll as PAY on PER.SSN = PAY.SSN

LEFT JOIN HumanResources as HR on PER.SSN = HR.SSN

GROUP BY SSN, Name

ORDER BY Pay_Date(DESC)
```

Comment: it's only the latest hire date.

Answer (score 0):

To get the row with the latest hire date:

```
SELECT
SSN, Name, Pay_Date, Hire_Date
FROM Personnel as PER
LEFT JOIN Payroll as PAY on PER.SSN = PAY.SSN
LEFT JOIN HumanResources as HR on PER.SSN = HR.SSN
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SSN, ORDER BY Hire_Date DESC)=1
ORDER BY Pay_Date DESC
```

Comment: You may not use ROW_NUMBER in a WHERE clause directly.

Comment: Really?   Good to know...thought I could take a short cut from the CTE that way.   I also didn't notice that the OP used the same SSN on all rows of his sample data, so your partition by is more correct than mine.  I think I will delete this answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions in this case are problematic because MAX() data for different columns can come from different rows in your set.

Instead, use window functions to discover what row in each group of SSNs has the highest (most recent) Hire_Date and then select your results from that subset.

```
SELECT SSN, Name, Pay_Date, Hire_Date
FROM
    (
    SELECT

        SSN
        , Name
        , Pay_Date
        , Hire_Date
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY SSN ORDER BY Hire_Date DESC) rn
    FROM
        Personnel as PER

        LEFT JOIN Payroll as PAY on PER.SSN = PAY.SSN

        LEFT JOIN HumanResources as HR on PER.SSN = HR.SSN
    ) x

WHERE 
    x.rn = 1

ORDER BY Pay_Date DESC
```

Comment: it keeps giving me the incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'.  When i hover over the error it says it's expecting AS,ID or QUOTED_ID. But those make no sense and when I try them they don't work anway

Comment: Sorry, a few syntax errors.  I added the alias 'x' and removed the parentheses from around (DESC).  Actually used the sqlfiddle from @Lamak to test and it should be good now.